# Open TCP ports on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to use my raspberry pi as a server, I have a java app using tcp port 1777 and mysql on 3306, however neither one or the other is accessible from lan (both works fine from the pi itself). When I scan the ports open on the pi from my laptop I only see the ssh and vnc ports, but when running the netstat on the pi both ports appear to be in listening state. I am running the latest version of raspbian (image had a ssh and vnc disabled by default, I enabled it in pi configuration (raspi-config)). Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, check which interface these services are listening on because the services listening on localhost are not 'binded' to the external network so try to make them listening on 192.**** ip address.

Example : **Edit MySQL configuration**

By default, MySQL is not configured to accept remote connections. You can enable remote connections by modifying the configuration file:

sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

and set `bind-address   = 192.**` or `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`   then restart mysql servic:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted the MySQL, I've change the port in java app to 1234 and that works as well,